# ReactJS set value using state component return undefined

Tags: reactjs, object, use-state

I have this piece of code, where i build a bunch of select and options, based on a stored object;
i also would like to set the "selected" value onChange, i store the selected value in a state, so everytime i rebuild the select (based on selection on real case i add or remove options) using the select state i reselect the previous value; but it seems it is not working, also if i set some defaults on the state it is not applied
i have the code here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-cherry-wsqyx?file=/src/App.js

i set one of the default

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState([{ Weigth: "250gr" }]);
```

but (even if using useEffect i can see that selected have a value) the value is not set in the select

the value is calculated as follow:

```
value={selected.find((o) => o.name === attribute.name)}
```

the result of find is "undefined", even if im quiete sure that o.name is Weigth and attribute.name is also Weight

what am i missing? any help?

Comment: here is the https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-gates-lgef5?file=/src/App.js let me know if this helps.

Comment: You've used `Weight` in one place and `Weigth` in the other, is it that?

Comment: Thank you @Matt fixed it but it wasnt it;

Comment: @NileshPatel using spread operator was my first attempt but it did not fit well with the rest of my code (anyway i got your suggestion to transfrom the select from array of object to object) thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your objects don't actually have a `name` key, you'd have to change your object to be something like:

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState([
    { name: 'Weight', value: "250gr" }
]);
```

Then get the value from the found object:

`value={selected.find(o => o.name === attribute.name)?.value}`

You could also consider using an object rather than an array to store the selected values:

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState({
    Weight: "250gr"
});
```

Then access the value directly by the key:

`value={selected[attribute.name]}`

Comment: Thank you! i simplified it to a plain object